# Convolution of Gaussian Function with itself

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convolution

Trying to solve this question:

> Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ be a Gaussian. Compute explicitly $(f*f)(x)$.

Using the definition of the convolution, and given the fact that the convolution of 2 Gaussians is another Gaussian, I got
\begin{align*}
(f*f)(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-y)f(y)\,dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2}e^{-y^2}\,dy
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you use the fact that convolution of two Gaussians is a Gaussian?

Comment: don't think i used it in the questions, but it is a well known property

Comment: You could rewrite the integrand so you can *complete the square* involving $y$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745174/convolution-of-two-gaussian-functions

Comment: Next step: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+2xy-2y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, complete the square to get $-a((y+b)^2+cx^2)$, then you could take $e^{-acx^2}$ beyond the sign of the integral since integration goes over $y$ and change the integration variable to $(y+b)$. Finally, use the well-known formula for the Gaussian integral. As an answer, I've got $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$