# Probability of making a bus connection

Tags: normal-distribution, alternative-proof, convolution

> You are travelling from $A$ to $C$. In order to reach your destination, you have to take two buses and make a transfer halfway at point $B$. The time at which bus 1 is expected to reach $B$ is normal distributed $T_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\text{12:00}, \text{$5^2$ min})$, and bus 2 is expected to leave at $T_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\text{12:02}, \text{$3^2$ min})$. What is the probability of making the connection?

I know the answer can be found by $P(T_1 - T_2 < 0)$ and do the $Z$ normalization with $Z = {T1 - T2 - (\text{12:00} - \text{12:02}) \over \sqrt{5^2 + 3^2}}$, but how does one prove this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for

I found some help through these questions

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383562/difference-between-two-random-variables
- [Convolution of two gaussian functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745174/convolution-of-two-gaussian-functions)

From the first question we can derive (I'm pretty sure I did the second step wrong)

$$\begin{align}
P(T_1 < T_2) &= 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{t_1}^\infty p_{T_1}(t_1)p_{T_2}(t_2)\,\mathrm dt_2\mathrm dt_1
\\
&= \color{red}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty p_{T_1}(t_1)p_{T_2}(t_2)\,\mathrm d(t_1-t_2)\mathrm dt_1}
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0 p_{T_1}(t_1)p_{-T_2}(-t_2)\mathrm dt_1\mathrm d(t_1-t_2)
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{T_1}(t_1)p_{-T_2}(t_1-t_2-t_1)\mathrm d t_1\mathrm d(t_1-t_2)
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 p_{T_1}\ast p_{-T_2}(t_1-t_2)\mathrm d(t_1-t_2)
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 p_{T_1-T_2}(t_1-t_2)\mathrm d(t_1-t_2)
\\
P(Z < 0) &= \int_{-\infty}^0 p_Z(z) \mathrm dz
\end{align}$$

And from the second question we can derive that the convolution between two normal distributions is

$$
X - Y = \mathcal N(\mu_1, \sigma_1) \ast \mathcal N(\mu_2, \sigma_2) = \mathcal N(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}) = Z
$$